# Qt Creator giving me [debug:/moc_scheduled.cpp] Error 1, and I have no idea why

Tags: c++, qt

My whole code seems to work and *to my knowledge* I've #included everything. Really really lost on this, and stressing about what to do! Someone please save me in my time of need! :))

Here's  my **scheduled.h** file:

```
#ifndef SCHEDULED_H
#define SCHEDULED_H
class Scheduled {

    Q_OBJECT


    public:
        Scheduled(string *start, string *end, int *boilerLvl);
        string* start;
        string* end;
        int* boilerlevel;
};
#endif
```

This is my **scheduled.cpp** file:

```
#include "scheduled.h"

Scheduled::Scheduled(string *startTime, string *endTime, int *boilerSet)
{

    start = startTime;
    end = endTime;
    boilerlevel = boilerSet;
};
```

All other files I use have #include "schedule.h" at the top of them, and throw off no errors.

My **makefile** looks like so:

```
QT += core gui widgets

CONFIG += c++11 console
QT     += widgets uitools



# DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    

SOURCES += \
        gui.cpp \
        main.cpp \
        main_copy.cpp \
        scheduled.cpp \
        screen1.cpp

qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    gui.h \
    scheduled.h \
    screen1.h \
    status.h

FORMS += \
    screen1.ui
```

And finally, the exact error I'm getting is:

**[Makefile.Debug:411 debug/moc_scheduled.cpp] Error 1**

Thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: Why do you use `Q_OBJECT` macro there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any object that uses `Q_OBJECT` in it's declaration should inherit from `QObject` class.

Remove the `Q_OBJECT` macro call.

Or change your header into something like:

```cpp
#ifndef SCHEDULED_H
#define SCHEDULED_H

#include <QObject>

class Scheduled : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Scheduled(string *start, string *end, int *boilerLvl);

public:
    string* start;
    string* end;
    int* boilerlevel;
};

#endif // SCHEDULED_H
```

Comment: Oh my lawrdy. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I had copied it from another .h file and just completely overlooked it. Sometimes things just need an extra set of eyes ;)

Comment: @JaymesonMichael If it helped you there should be an accept button somewhere above (click the tick mark, or up vote maybe).